# Working with wide SQL tables using ScalaQuery (or something else type-safe)

Tags: sql, scala, scalaquery

Many databases have tables with many columns, but ScalaQuery uses tuples to represent table schemas, and Scala doesn't support such wide tuples. Is there any way to work with such tables using ScalaQuery (short of dropping down to executing raw SQL)? If not, is there any other type-safe querying language that supports this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Squeryl](http://squeryl.org/index.html) is a Scala MySQL ORM that appears to map table rows to classes using name equivalence, so it should have no problem working with many-column tables.  I personally haven't used this but it looks fairly easy to use.

Comment: There is no coupling between Squeryl and MySQL.  There are database adapters available for PostgreSQL, Oracle, DB2, Derby and H2 as well.  Tables are mapped to POSO objects, so there is no limit to the number of columns, and queries are extremely type safe.  It's easier to point you at the documentation (http://squeryl.org/selects.html) on that than to explain it here.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Mapped projections to the rescue! http://szeiger.de/blog/2009/09/27/a-scala-query-update/</strike>

Comment: This still constructs intermediate tuples, no?

Comment: Yep, projections are backed by tuples :(